# User log in in to android app through Facebook

Tags: android

I have created one app but i want authonticate the user by making user to log  in through Facebook..how to make my android app to log in with users Facebook account?

Comment: What have you tried yet? Try to be more specific, there are dozens of tutorials out there. What worked, what did not work? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to integrate Facebook SDK , follow developer.facebook.com. Try the initial steps.